# function onclick event listener that runs a function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a rock paper scissors game. Whatever button clicked is the players selection and then a function called to decide computers selection and then run the game, add the scores to its corresponding variables.
I have tried a lot of different methods and this is as far as I came. For some reason the function does not even return the selections. Here is my code:

```js
let wins = 0;

let losses = 0;

let draws = 0

const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('button');

buttons.forEach((button) => {
    button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        function game() {
            playerSelection = e.target.id;
            computerSelection = computerPlay();

            let computerPlay = () => {
                let choices = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
                let computerSelection = choices[Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length)];
                return computerSelection;
            }
            let playRound = (playerSelection, computerSelection) => {

                let won = 'You win! You beat ' + computerSelection + '.';
                let lost = 'You lose! ' + computerSelection + ' beats you.';
                let draw = 'Draw! You both chose ' + computerSelection + '!';
                if ((playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'rock') || (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'paper') || (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'scissors')) {
                    ++draws;
                    return draw;

                } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
                    ++wins;
                    return won;

                } else if (playerSelection == 'rock' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
                    ++losses;
                    return lost;

                } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
                    ++wins;
                    return won;

                } else if (playerSelection == 'paper' && computerSelection == 'scissors') {
                    ++losses;
                    return lost;

                } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'paper') {
                    ++wins;
                    return won;

                } else if (playerSelection == 'scissors' && computerSelection == 'rock') {
                    ++losses;
                    return lost;

                } else {
                    alert('Somethings not right.');

                }
                alert("Player score is " + wins, "Computer score is " + losses, "Ties =" + draws);
            };
            return playRound(playerSelection, computerSelection);
        };
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         <button  id="rock">Rock</button>
         <button  id="paper">Paper</button>
         <button  id="scissors">Scissors</button>
         <div class="results"></div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Warning**: You are using implicit globals. [Use strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Comment: Additionally what Quentin says in their answer, you're using `computerPlay` in the temporal dead-zone. It's also not clear, where exactly are you expecting to get the return value of `game`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's simplify what you have a lot (there's a reason that SO expects you to provide a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and not wack a couple of dozen lines of irrelevant code into the question):

```js
x.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    function do_something() {
        alert("x");
    }

});
```

```html
<button id="x">Click me</button>
```

Your event listener defines a function (named `game` in your example). And that's it. You never call the function. So it does nothing.

---

Remove `function game() {` and the matching `}`. Then you will get error messages in the console about the other errors you have made.

```js
x.addEventListener("click", function (event) {

    //function do_something() {
        alert("x");
    //}

});
```

```html
<button id="x">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot again! Now when the button is clicked I get the playerSelection and computerSelection. That's improvement. But again I think I declare playRound but I do not call it. This is my first DOM exercise, and It seems like I do not really have a good understanding of functions. How do you figure I call the playRound and return the string that says you win or lost?